# Why are null values returned when LOAD CSV in noe4j?

Tags: csv, import, neo4j, cypher

I run the following in Cypher Language:

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM
'file:///arrivals_country.csv' As lines FIELDTERMINATOR ';'
WITH lines
Limit 3
Return lines.Region, toFloat(lines.Value), toInt(lines.Year), toInt(lines.Month), lines.Country
```

The following null values are returned in the query:

```
lines.Region    toFloat(lines.Value)    toInt(lines.Year)   toInt(lines.Month)  lines.Country
null               70378                     1978                  null             null
null               16730.1                   1978                  null             null
null               4203.2                    1978                  null             null
```

But these are the contents from the csv file:

```
Year    Month   Region  Country     Value
1978    1        Asia   ASEAN       70378
1978    1        Asia   Japan       16730.1
1978    1        Asia   Hong Kong   4203.2
```

Comment: Show example of csv file.

Comment: also best with headers

Comment: @stdob-- example of the csv file is written at the bottom of my question

Comment: @ChristopheWillemsen the example of csv file is written under " But these are the actual values from the csv file"

Comment: He said the **exact** file contents, not the values.

Comment: Also my comment was before you edited ;-)

Comment: @ChristopheWillemsen yes, I edited it. Any idea what is going wrong?

Comment: @Technologic27 This is not an example of a file - there are no separators, although there are in your query.

Comment: @stdob-- but that is exactly how my file looks like. I delimited the csv file before using it.

Comment: @Technologic27 In your query you use a semicolon as a separator. In the example of a file a semicolon is not the point. Give an example file as it is. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you have spaces around the values (or even the headers)

Try to run this and look at the strings, if they have spaces you have to use `toInt(trim(x))`

```
LOAD CSV FROM
'file:///arrivals_country.csv' As lines FIELDTERMINATOR ';'
RETURN lines limit 5;
```

Comment: Thank you but I tried that and it still doesn't work.